# How to get an accurate duration of any audio file quickly?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, decode, duration, libav

There are many audio files in the wild encoded with VBR which don't have an accurate duration tag, and command line FFMpeg would output the following:

> Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate

(and indeed, it is)

Using `libav`, we can see that this is tested with the `has_duration()` function from `libavformat/utils.c`

I have an audio player that needs to get an accurate duration information using `libav`. I've tried completely decoding the file and counting the total number of samples decoded which is the usual recommendation (and is accurate), but this can take 10+ seconds on a 60 minute audio file, which is not acceptable.

I notice that there are some closed source audio decoders and music playing apps which can get an accurate duration for these files immediately. There must be some cheap way of determining the accurate duration? Perhaps a snippet or high-level description would help me out.

Comment: "I've tried completely decoding the file..." Can you get an accurate enough estimate by sampling the first few seconds and extrapolating, instead of the whole file?

Comment: With variable bit-rate MP3 files, scanning the entire file is only way to do it.  You don't necessarily need to decompress the whole file, but you would need to read each MP3 chunk header, which should be relatively fast.

Comment: Otherwise, all constant bit-rate audio files have everything you need in the header.  And I would think libavformat would support this.

Comment: I think you should be able to do "demux"-only (there's not really any muxing but it still parses the packets out of the stream) with libavformat instead of decoding, in which case it should be near-instant. But I wonder if you're doing something wrong to make the decoding so slow. I remember mp3 decoding being over 500x realtime decades ago so it should be far faster now...

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE  ffmpeg -i *.mp3 -f null -  using prebuilt ffmpeg on my late model desktop is 1550x which is still a couple seconds for 60+ min tracks. On Android (my target) its much slower. Thanks for the demuxing tip, maybe that's the solution

Comment: @SteveM Try adding `-c copy` output option to your command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to "demux" the track very quickly and examine the duration of each packet to determine the total duration of the track, decoding is not necessary.

Simply adding durations in a loop until EOF is reached:

```
int read = av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, packet);
durationSeconds += packet->duration * (double) timebase;
```

Comment: For mp3 it gives the same result as `formatContext->duration / AV_TIME_BASE` in my tests, which is not accurate. Maybe it has to do with the first and last frames having the encoder padding, but without decoding the whole file it cannot be detected.